# Local variable referenced before assignment in script node?

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I am doing a little project using animation nodes and I used a script in the node tree but it keep saying "Local variable referenced before assignment",I used global before the variable and it say "Syntax error".

My code is just as simple as :

```
if Bool == 1 :
    Always = 1
```

here is my node:
[image: Nodes]
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: a little bit more context would be helpful.., can you maybe add a screenshot to your question? And is the variable Bool declared somewhere?

Comment: @JacquesLucke I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't assign a value to the 'Always' variable in all cases.

AN takes your code and makes a function from it that is executed by the Invoke Subprogram node. The generated code looks like so:

[image]

Line 16 throws the error here because you haven't used 'Always' before.
You can fix by changing your code to something like this:

```
if Bool == 1:
    Always = 1
else:
    Always = 0
```

Comment: well,I cant return a value if it is not equal to 1,I have an object that moves and if this object touches another object a text will appear but after the object go away and they not touching anymore the text will disappear,but I want it to stay after the first touch,so I was hopping hat this script will assign 1 to the Always variable after the first touch and it wont disappear.is there is another way to do that?

Comment: Unfortunally this isn't really possible, because it is simulation: The current frame depends on the frames before.
AN can't do simulation in nice ways.

Comment: well,can I write a script that do something if the value is 1 in animation nodes,like creating a custom property?

Comment: Yes sure. The problem is when do you want to reset this property when you go backwards in time.

Comment: I won't use frames then,I will create the custom property if the objects touch.